# How do I move a row in one data frame to a column in another data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to move a row in one data frame to add it to make a new column in another data frame. I have frame d1:

```
   x     y
1 VBR 33333
2 VEA 33333
3 VTV 33333
```

and frame sh:

```
                VBR      VEA      VTV
2014-02-04 360.9457 875.3501 469.1532
```

sh started out as a zoo class but I have tried converting both frames to matrix or data frame and using merge and nothing seems to work.

When I try merge (d1, shares) I get:

```
   x     y      VBR      VEA      VTV
1 VBR 33333 360.9457 875.3501 469.1532
2 VEA 33333 360.9457 875.3501 469.1532
3 VTV 33333 360.9457 875.3501 469.1532
```

What I want is:

```
1  VBR 33333 360.9457
2  VEA 33333 875.3501
3  VTV 33333 469.1532
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
cbind(d1, t(sh))
```

This should work for you.

`cbind()` combines `data.frames` by column and `t()` transposes `sh` from 1 row and 3 columns to 3 rows and 1 column.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Rats! Have used cbind before but just overlooked it. Perfect!